# Show that Kolmogorov's axioms imply that P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B) for any events A and B

Tags: probability

Show that Kolmogorov's axioms $(P(A) ≥ 0, P(A∪B) = P(A) +
P(B)$ if $AB = ∅, P(S = 1))$ implies that
$P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) − P(A ∩ B)$
for any events $A$ and $B$.

I've sketched figures for this problem for different possible scenarios (ex. $P(A) = 0$ and $P(B) = 1$, $P(A) = 1$, $P(B) = 0$, $P(A) =  .5, P(B) = .5)$ and I know it's true. I don't understand how you can prove it though.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Recall that:
$$
\begin{align*}
A &= (A \cap B) \cup (A \setminus B) \\
B &= (A \cap B) \cup (B \setminus A) \\
A \cup B &= (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B) \cup (B \setminus A)
\end{align*}
$$
where any two of the sets being unioned are disjoint.

Comment: What does the "\" symbol mean in probability?

Comment: It's a symbol from set theory, meaning set difference. You might have seen it as a minus symbol instead. In general:
$$
S \setminus T = S \cap \overline T = \{s \in S \mid s \notin T\}
$$
where $\overline T$ denotes the complement of $T$ (the set of all things that are **not** in $T$).